Why Am I Not Able to Notify Some Users in Comments Using @?
My question arises from observing that if I try to notify user M.Riyan or user Prem by using @ and commenting, the part addressing them using @ disappears and only rest of the comment is visible once posted. Further, I noticed that when I usually want to notify a user using @ in the comments, their name shows up in a white box on the top of where I am typing(which enables the whole username to be typed when the Tab key is pressed), but in case of these users, it didn't; I manually had to type their names. Also, even if I type the first $3$ characters of their usernames after @ and comment, that part disappears  too.
I tried this for a few times but this happened each time. With other users, however, this problem did not occur. Why does this happen? Is this simply a glitch or is there an option in a user's profile to disable others from referring them using @?
I tried to look up this question on Meta Stack Exchange but could not find any links that focused on my question. If there is a link however, please share it by commenting and kindly don't downvote or vote to close this question without any explanation.

Welcome to Math Meta. Based on both of those users you mention being the authors of the posts you linked to, I believe that what you're asking about is addressed in the Meta Stack Exchange FAQ post's How do comment @replies work? answer which states in its initial Who can be notified with this feature? section that "... if there are no comments, or only you or the author have commented on the post so far, the '@'name will be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value". ...

(cont.) Nonetheless, note that if you really want to use their name, it also says right afterwards that "To avoid breaking sentences, mentions not at the beginning will not be removed".

@JohnOmielan thanks for the clarification! So now that my query is resolved, what should I do with this post?

See also: Why does @someone sometimes disappear from comments? and Making your comments heard.

As John Omielan has commented, this occurence takes place when no one or only the author of the post and a second person(facing this 'issue') have commented on the post and @ followed by the name of the author is used at the beginning of a comment. This is because as mentioned in the answer How do comment @replies work?, it is simply redundant. But such mentions which are not at the beginning of a comment would not be affected.
